# Generate the list of all possible mappings in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

Suppose we have a mapping K -> V, where the domain, K, is a set([1,2,3]) and the co-domain, V ,is drawn from the set(['a', 'b','c']). Is there a concise way to enumerate as an iterable (ideally a list or generator of dictionaries), all possible mappings:

Eg.

```
[ { 1 : 'a', 2 : 'a', 3 : 'a' },
  { 1 : 'a', 2 : 'a', 3 : 'b' },
  { 1 : 'a', 2 : 'b', 3 : 'a' },
  ...
  { 1 : 'c', 2 : 'c', 3 : 'c' }
]
```

Note that the domain is not fixed in size, so this kind of solution isn't ideal:

```
[ { 1 : x, 2 : y,  3 : z } for x in V for y in V for z in V ]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Use the `repeat` argument to [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
K = set([1, 2, 3])
V = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
itertools.product(V, repeat=len(K))
```

You can then construct the `dict`s in a comprehension:

```
(dict(zip(K, x)) for x in itertools.product(V, repeat=len(K)))
```

Checking:

```
>>> len([dict(zip([1, 2, 3], x)) for x in itertools.product('abc', repeat=3)])
27
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
K,V = [1,2,3], 'abc'
[dict(zip(K, p)) for p in itertools.product(V, repeat=len(V))]
```